# C-Style Unions in C#

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I apologize for the naming of these fields, but I'm have to block out things like field names based on an NDA.

So basically I am in C# and I am using Interop to communicate with an external library, which requires specific structures to be passed by reference, one of which uses a union.  This is the struct that seems to be giving me a headache, because I have found a few references online on how to union two data types but not two structs together.  Here are the basics of the two struct

```
struct datatype1
{ 
    char field1; 
    char field2; 
    char field3;
    char field4;
    char field5; 
    char field6; 
    char field7; 
};

struct datatype2
{
    public uint field8;
    public uint field9;
}

struct datatype3
{
    unsigned int field10;
    union
    {
        datatype1 field11;
        datatype2 field12;
    } field13;
    uint field14;
    unsigned char field15;
    uint field16;
}
```

What would the resulting structs look like in c#?  I have had a few ideas, some of which seem to work but result in a blue screen with a message of reference_by_pointer after a while, and I was thinking that maybe some thing about my struct definition is wrong, and somehow the data is not fitting in the struct correctly.  Here is what I currently have:

```
    [StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
    public struct datatype1
    {
        public byte field1;
        public byte field2;
        public byte field3;
        public byte field4;
        public byte field5;
        public byte field6;
        public byte field7;
    }

    [StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
    public struct datatype2
    {
        public uint field8; // Digital i/p event
        public uint field9;
    }

    public struct datatype3
    {
        public uint field10;

        [StructLayout( LayoutKind.Explicit )]
        public struct AnonymousStruct
        {
            [FieldOffset( 0 )]
            public datatype1 field11;

            [FieldOffset( 0 )]
            public datatype2 field12;
        }

        public AnonymousStruct field13;

        public uint field14;

        public byte[] field15;

        public uint field16;
    }
```

Am I doing this all wrong?

**EDIT:  In response to a request for more info, here is an example usage, but not that I cannot provide the population of the fields because that is hidden in the API.**

Also, it is possible it is a problem with the API, but that is more unlikely than me screwing up the Interop to it.

```
    ...inside thread....
    datatype3 dt = new datatype3();
    while( true )
    {
        api.get_next_value( ref dt );
        PrintData( dt );
        Thread.Sleep( 55 );
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Prints the data from the event.  Used for debugging purposes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="evp"></param>
    private void PrintData( datatype3 evp )
    {
        if( evp.field10 == 2 )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "datatype2" );
            Console.WriteLine( "\tfield8val: " + evp.field13.field12.field8);
            Console.WriteLine( "\tfield9val: " + evp.field13.field12.field9 );
        }
        else if( evp.de_type == 1 )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "datatype1" );
            Console.WriteLine( "\tfield1val:  " + evp.field13.field12.field1 );
            Console.WriteLine( "\tfield2val:  " + evp.field13.field12.field2 );
            Console.WriteLine( "\tfield3val:  " + evp.field13.field12.field3 );
            Console.WriteLine( "\tfield4val:  " + evp.field13.field12.field4 );
            Console.WriteLine( "\tfield5val:  " + evp.field13.field12.field5 );
            Console.WriteLine( "\tfield6val:  " + evp.field13.field12.field6 );
            Console.WriteLine( "\tfield7val:  " + evp.field13.field12.field7 );
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

I apologize for not being able to provide absolute calls or true context, but I must honor NDA's even if it means reducing the quality of answers.

**EDIT 2: Is it at all possible that the two different sized datatypes being unioned together is having any affect on this situation?  I know that datatype1 has size of 7 bytes and datatype2 has a size of 8 bytes.  Could this cause some sort of memory issue?**

Comment: Could you expand more on the exact errors/problems your example code is causing? E.g. is it the interop that's failing, or does it not work at all even in C#? If it's the interop, could you mock up an example of how you're doing it (from both sides)?

Comment: You've declared field15 differently for starters, but that may not be the cause of the problem. A bigger issue here is that the C declarations you've given don't really tell you the whole story about their in-memory layout, because it's generally left to the compiler to align/pack the data, and you need to explicitly state otherwise. e.g. You might expect the char in field15 to consume 1 byte, but there will probably be 3 unused bytes between it and field16, due to alignment chosen by the C compiler. Solution would be to manually verify the layout for both the C and C#, assert they match.

Comment: @Cameron The code itself will compile and run fine for a few minutes but after several minutes of invoking a call to the method which uses the struct, eventually the machine blue screens.  I will edit my question in a few minutes to include an example of usage.

Comment: @MarkH How would I check this?  I assume I would need to fire up a c compiler and a c# compiler and ensure that their memory footprint is the same.  Is there a better way?

Comment: @MarkH The C# layout will match the C layout assuming that the C code is compiled with default alignment.

Comment: @David - What's the *default alignment*? The C standard doesn't specify one, afaik. I was making a point that it's implementation defined, so one shouldn't assume particular layout. (Although if you're using a particular compiler on a particular platform, you can assume the default alignment of that implementation.)

Comment: @Chuck - You can make an instance of your type and take the address of each field, or as you suggest, run both compilers and manually inspect the memory used by the structs.

Comment: @Mark All sane Windows C compilers use the same rules for alignment. Alignment is unlikely to be the issue. The C standard isn't really the issue here. This is Windows.

Comment: I missed where windows was mentioned in the question. C# runs on much more than windows and x86.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem with your C# union. However, `field15` is wrong. It's `char` in the C code and `byte[]` in the C# code. You need to declare it as `byte` in the C# code.

For what it's worth, you are safe to omit `LayoutKind.Sequential` since that is the default for a struct.

Comment: sizeof(byte[]) == 4 (8 on 64-bit). sizeof(byte) == 1

Comment: @ColeJohnson Even if they were the same size it would be broken.

Comment: I know. I'm just pointing out that the size of a pointer isn't the same size as a byte

Comment: I switched the byte[] to a byte and it seemed to make no difference.  I will leave that change in there but there is definetly something else going on.

Comment: @ChuckRussell: What exactly is the `uint` data type defined as in the C code? `unsigned int`, or something else? And are you sure your code says `public uint field8;`? ... that's not valid C or C++ code. :P

Comment: @ChuckRussell Your union is fine. It's easy enough for you to check all that by writing a DLL that receives one of your structs, and logs what was sent to it.

Comment: @Mehrdad Yeah I copied that from the C# implementation of that because I couldn't find the reference for it in the API, but it is an unsigned int